# Python - loop through list to count vowels and put the numbers in a dictionary

Tags: python

I need to write a program where I have a list of names of counties and I need to find how many of each of the 5 vowels is in that list and put the 5 numbers in a dictionary.

I wanted to make a for-loop to go through each vowel, and each time it goes through the loop, add a new entry in a dictionary, with the vowel as the key and the count as the value.

It should print: `{'a':4, 'e':4, 'i':4, 'o':4, 'u':4}`. I don't know how many of the vowels there are so I just wrote 4 for all the values in the example. 
The list of counties is really long so I just pasted a shortened version here.

```
counties = ['Autauga','Baldwin','Barbour','Bibb','Blount','Bullock','Butler','Calhoun','Chambers','Cherokee','Chilton','Choctaw','Clarke','Clay','Cleburne','Coffee','Colbert','Conecuh','Coosa','Covington','Crenshaw','Cullman','Dale','Dallas']

letter = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') 

counter = 0 

d={} 

for it in clist:
    def func(clist, letterlist, count): 
        count += clist.count(letterlist)
        print("the number of vowels:" count) 
        return count 

    func(counties, letter, counter)
```

As you can see, I am very new to Python and have no idea what I am doing. I can't get it to work and definitely can't get it in a dictionary.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you actually creating and calling the function **inside** the  loop?

Comment: Also, I don't understand why the output would be `{'a':4, 'e':4, 'i':4, 'o':4, 'u':4}`. The numbers are off

Comment: Work through a tutorial on the `collections.Counter` type.  Your program can be *very* short.

Comment: What's the purpose of `for it in clist:` if you never use the `it` variable?

Comment: How can you have `for it in clist:` outside the function whose parameter is `clist`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested `for` loops to iterate over the `counties` list and the characters of each county, and keep incrementing the output dict with the character as the key if the character is in the `vowels` list:

```
d = {}
for county in counties:
    for character in county.lower():
        if character in vowels:
            d[character] = d.get(character, 0) + 1
```

`d` becomes:

```
{'a': 16, 'u': 10, 'i': 4, 'o': 14, 'e': 14}
```

Alternatively, you can use `collections.Counter` with a generator expression that extracts the vowel characters from the list of strings:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(c for county in counties for c in county.lower() if c in vowels)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're trying to do what I've put below (I've omitted your list of countries). I tried to add comments, and you can add print lines to see what each piece of code is doing.

```
vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i','o', 'u') 

d={} 

## select countries 1 at a time
for country in countries:
    # convert each country to lowercase, to match list of vowels, otherwise, you need to deal with upper and lowercase
    country = country.lower()
    # select letter in country 1 at a time
    for i in range(len(country)):
        # check to see whether the letter selected in the country, the ith letter, is a vowel
        if (country[i] == 'a') or (country[i] == 'e') or (country[i] == 'i') or (country[i] == 'o') or (country[i] == 'u'):
            # if the ith letter is a vowel, but is not yet in the dictionary, add it
            if (country[i]) not in d:
                d[country[i]] = 1
            # if the ith letter is a vowel, and is already in the dictionary, then increase the counter by 1
            else:
                d[country[i]] += 1

print(d) # {'a': 16, 'u': 10, 'i': 4, 'o': 14, 'e': 14}
```